# 96 bit long double and too short stX registers

Tags: nasm

Let's consider:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
long double a=1.20, b=12.0;
std::cout << sizeof(long double);
add(a,b);
return 0;
}


g++ -m32 -o main main.cpp
```

After executing it turned out that size of long double is 12 bytes.

So, now, I would like to implement `add` function in 32-bit nasm.
How can I deal with addition floating points number? It is not a problem, just use FPU and fadd you can say. But, I have 12 byte number ( 96 bit). Our FPU registers are 80 bit. So it is a problem.

And another issue, I looked at code generated by `gcc`:
    objdump -d main > main.s  -M intel

( I know about -S flag, but I got used to `objdump`) and for addition long doubles the generated code is following:

```
 80486e1:   db 6d c8                fld    TBYTE PTR [ebp-0x38]
 80486e4:   db 6d d8                fld    TBYTE PTR [ebp-0x28]
 80486e7:   de c1                   faddp  st(1),st
```

How is it possible? After all, we have 80 bit registers and compiler try to load 96 bit numbers to them.

Please make clear my mind. :)

Comment: Only 80 bits are used, since that's the size of double extended precision floating-point values on x86. The compiler is choosing to use 12 bytes to store those 10 bytes in memory, for whatever reason.

Comment: ok, so now it is clear. Thanks :)